# Terraform, format output for Ansible inventory

Tags: ansible, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have Terraform scripts that create instances with some count. After it's done creating, I need to form an inventory file for Ansible. Currently I'm doing it with `resource "aws_instance"` and for output I use `resource "local_file"`. It works fine for a single instance like this

```
resource "local_file" "hosts_file" {
    content     = <<EOF
[WINDOWS]
${var.win_ip}

[LINUX]
${var.linux_ip}
```

But now I need to set count for `win` instances more than 1 and put first instance IP into the `[WINDOWS]` group, but the rest of `win` instances should go to another group `[ANOTHER]`
.

```
resource "local_file" "hosts_file" {
    content     = <<EOF
[WINDOWS]
${var.win_ip[0]} someVariable=${var.win_ip[0].tag.Name}

[ANOTHER]
${var.win_ip[1]} someVariable=${var.win_ip[1].tag.Name}
${var.win_ip[2]} someVariable=${var.win_ip[2].tag.Name}

[LINUX]
${var.linux_ip}
```

Output of `aws_instance` is like this `value = join(", ", aws_instance.node[*].public_ip)`

Is there a way to achieve it with Terraform?

Comment: Can you clarify, how `var.win_ip` relates to `value = join(", ", aws_instance.node[*].public_ip`? `var.win_ip` is some user provided variable?

Comment: Have you considered using Ansible dynamic inventory for AWS. 
[Working with Dynamic Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#working-with-dynamic-inventory)

Comment: `var.win_ip` it's literally `value = join(", ", aws_instance.node[*].public_ip`.